# Read from multiple files and compact to a single file

Tags: hadoop

New to Hadoop.

The data is getting loaded in to multiple files in different directories. The task is to read multiple files and write/compact to a single file. Can you share what are the best options to achieve this task.

Answer (score 0):

Use [cat](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#cat) and pipe the result to [put](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.4.1/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/FileSystemShell.html#put)

```
hadoop fs -cat /directorypath/*.txt | hadoop fs -put - outputfilepath.txt
```